# One player can win several times in giveaway command (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Syntax of the command is: !giveaway (how many winner) (time) (prize) 
Then you can react to have a chance to win but: The problem is a user who reacts can win several times. I don't know how to fix that

````js
message.delete();
    var item = "";
    var time;
    var winnerCount
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    for (var i = 3; i < messageArray.length; i++) {
        item += (messageArray[i] + " ");

    }
    winnerCount = (messageArray[1]);
    if(!winnerCount) return message.channel.send("You must specify the number of winners!");
   time = (messageArray[2]);
   if(!time) return message.channel.send("You have to specify the time of the giveaway!")
    if(!item) return message.channel.send("You have to specify the prize of the giveaway!")
var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor(item)
.setDescription(`React with  to enter! ${winnerCount} Winner(s)`)
.setFooter(`The giveaway lasts ${time} and was started at ${date.format(now, 'YYYY/MM/DD')} / ${date.format(now, 'HH:mm:ss')}!`)
var embedSent = await message.channel.send(embed);
embedSent.react("");
setTimeout(function() {
var peopleReacted = embedSent.reactions.get("").users.filter(user => user.id !== client.user.id).array()
if(peopleReacted.length === 0) return message.channel.send("Unfortunately, nobody took part in the giveaway! :(")
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length)
var winners = [];
var winnerMessage = "";
for (var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
    winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);

}
for (var i = 0; i < winners.length; i++) {
    winnerMessage += (winners[i].toString() + " ");

}
let haveHas = winners.length === 1 ? "has" : "have"

if(winnerCount < winners.length) return;
message.channel.send(winnerMessage + "" + haveHas + ` won **${item}**`);
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor(`${item}`)
.setDescription(`Winner(s): ${winnerMessage}`)
.setFooter(`The giveaway ended!`)
embedSent.edit(embed)
}, ms(time))```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is within these lines :

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length)
var winners = [];
var winnerMessage = "";
for (var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
    winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);

}
```

I'd suggest pushing the winners to an array. When selecting a new winner, check if it already exists in the array, if not then push, else draw a new winner.

Am no javacript expert, but something like :

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length)
var winners = [];
var winnerMessage = "";
for (var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
    if(! winners.includes(index)) winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);
    else i--; // Don't progress the loop if no winner is selected.
}
```

Comment: Note to the OP: notice how this answer describes a potential solution in words. This is often a good place to start. Break down what you want to do into small steps and write them out in English (or whatever written language you like).l

Comment: Jesse was kind enough to add the i-- to the code (as to not increment the loop if no winner is selected) You could give this version a spin. Thanks Jesse!

Comment: Whoops I forgot to put the `else` statement *facepalm*. You mind adding that in @Dexirian?

Comment: With that code: After I entered the command no other commands working anymore? (And the giveaway command also)

Comment: Yea you have to change the line that I added from `i++;` to `else i++;` or it just loops. Also you may want to add and if statement to make sure the number of winners is less than or equal to the number of people entered.

Comment: Also put your `var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length)` at the beginning of the for loop. That should fix both issues.

Comment: If I write that you can still win several times. What is that if statement I have to write?

Comment: I'll try it, Jesse

Comment: So?  ```var winners = [];
var winnerMessage = ""; 
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length)

for (var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
 
    if(! winners.includes(index)) winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);
    else i--; // Don't progress the loop if no winner is selected.
 
}```

Comment: Where should I put var index [...] ? (I don't understand)

Comment: Put it on the first line inside the for loop.

Comment: Under for (var i [..] it comes the same result (you can still win several times

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length)
> var winners = [];
> var winnerMessage = "";
> for (var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
>     winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);
> }
> ```

Since you only define the index once, the same user is being pushed into the `winners` array each iteration of the `for` loop.

Determine a new winner each time and remove the selected winner from the selection pool so that they can't be selected again.

```js
if (peopleReacted.length < winnerCount) { // Make sure there's enough users, not just 0
  return message.channel.send("Unfortunately, not enough users took part in the giveaway! :(")
    .catch(console.error);
}

const winners = [];
const winnerMessage = "";

for (let i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length);
  winners.push(peopleReacted[index]); // Pick a randomly selected user as a winner
  peopleReacted.splice(index, 1); // Remove that user from the pool to be selected from
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Dexirian said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57794661/10601203),

> Problem is within these lines :

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * peopleReacted.length);
var winners = [];
var winnerMessage = "";
for (var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
    winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);
}
```

> I'd suggest pushing the winners to an array. When selecting a new winner, check if it already exists in the array, if not then push, else draw a new winner.

I want to add to that by mentioning that you only pick one index and re-use it, thus the same person is added to `winners` every time. I would do the following:

```
var winners = [];
var winnerMessage = "";
if(peopleReacted.length < winnerCount){
   winners = peopleReacted; // Add everyone to the list of winners if the number of participants is less than or equal to the number winners
}
else{
    let index = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < winnerCount; i++){
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (peopleReacted.length - 1)); // Subtract 1 from peopleReacted.length to prevent an Array Out of Bounds exception
        if(!winners.includes(peopleReacted[index])) winners.push(peopleReacted[index]);
        else i--; // Don't progress the loop if no winner is selected.
    }
}
```

And that should do it. Let me know if you have any questions!